# Unable to remove additional double quotes in json string added by python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file whose contents are

```
{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}
```

When I read the file using python, I get the string as

```
"{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}"
```

I want the double quotes to be removed from the beginning and end of the string. From python docs , I came to know that python adds double quotes by itself if there are single quotes in the string to avoid escaping.

Comment: there isn't actually a double quote.

Comment: Are you sure the json is correct? JSON requires `double quotes for string if I am not wrong, not single quotes, which seems to be what your file contains? The double quotes at the begining and end just indicate that its a string, its not actually part of the string.

Comment: How are you viewing the contents of the file? If you're on the interactive prompt, make sure to use `print my_file_contents` rather than just `my_file_contents`, since the latter will show you the outer quotes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the JSON? If you write it out to a file right after, for example, there won't be any double quotes. They're just added because you're reading it in as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the files as stored are intended to be JSON then they are invalid. The JSON format doesn't allow the use of single quotes to delimit strings. **Assuming you have no single quotes within the key/value strings** themselves, you can replace the single quotes with double quotes and then read in using the JSON module:

```
import json
x = "{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}"
x = x.replace("'", '"')
j = json.loads(x)
print j
```

yields:

```
{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}
```

**Alternatively:**

If the data is the string representation of a Python `dict`, you can read it in with `eval`. Using `eval` is dangerous (see [Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)'s thoughts on it). That said, if you wrote the file yourself and you are confident that it contains no malicious code, you can use `eval` to read the string as Python source code:

```
x = "{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}"
eval(x, {'__builtins__': {}})
```

yields:

```
{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}
```

Don't make a habit of this though! The right way to do this is to save the data to a file in a proper serialization format and then to read it from disk using a library like the `json` module.

Answer (score 0):

If your string actually contains double quotes (which it might not, as they could just be part of the printed representation), you could get rid of them with a slice, e.g.,

```
>>> hello = '"hello more stuff things"'
>>> hello
'"hello more stuff things"'
>>> hello[1:-1]
'hello more stuff things'
```

Note in this case that the outer single quotes are not part of the string, they are just part of the printed representation.

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes you are referring to are not part of the string, and are just there to delimit it.

If you assign the string "thi's'" to a variable:

`>>> a = "thi's'"`

the first element in that string is `t`:

`>>> a[0]`

`t`

In your example, the first element in the string would be `{`, which I believe is what you would expect.

Comment: You write "are part of the string". That should be "are **not** a part of the string".

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `string` back to `dictionary` using

```
import re
x="{'FileID': 'a3333.txt','Timestamp': '2014-12-05T02:01:28.271Z','SuccessList':'a,b,c,d,e'}"
print dict(re.findall(r"""'([^']*)'\s*:\s*'([^']*)'""",x))
```