# Parsing an array from Flask to Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I am trying to parse an array that I have retrieved from my flask server. The array is as follows.

```
"[{\"firstName\": \"Roy\", \"lastName\": \"Augustine\"}]"
```

I am parsing the array in Android studio using the following code.

```
private void loadDrives() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://142.93.216.24:5000/",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        //traversing through all the object
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            //adding the product to product list
                            driveList.add(new TestMl(
                                    jsonObject.getString("firstName"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("lastName")
                            ));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

I am however getting the following error.

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value [{"firstName": "Roy", "lastName": "Augustine"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The error suggests that the json is being successfully retrieved, but it cannot parse the array successfully. Could anybody suggest a suitable solution?

Comment: Even after converting to jsonArray, it still gives me the same error. Check my updated code @PrasanthS

Comment: have you removed double quotes at start and end of JSON response?

Comment: `Value [{"firstName": "Roy", "lastName": "Augustine"}] of type java.lang.String` this showing that your JSON is not Object or Array but its `String`

Comment: How do i parse the string? Thats my question @AliAhmed

Comment: you're generating this JSON using some code. you have to handle this from your Server

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972419/unable-to-remove-additional-double-quotes-in-json-string-added-by-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu're fetch data using wrong name.. it is `lastName` not `lastname`

Change this

```
driveList.add(new TestMl(
array.getString("firstname"),
array.getString("lastname")
));
```

To

```
driveList.add(new TestMl(
array.getString("firstName"),
array.getString("lastName")
));
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. On line JSONObject array = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: problem is double quotes at start and end of your JSON .. remove those

Comment: I cannot change the json as it is automatically generated from Flask server @Ali Ahmed